# Insert columns from another table as well as text

Tags: sql, insert, append

So here's the thing my target table (T) and source table (S) look like this.

```
+----+----+ 
| T  | S  | 
+----+----+ 
| PO | PO | 
| VE | VE | 
| TE |    | 
+----+----+
```

I need a script that will insert the columns from the source into target and in the TE field I need it to insert the text "source1"

I've been playing around (unsuccessfully) with this:

```
insert into target
   (PO, VE, TE)
   select PO, VE, 'source1' from source
```

thank you in advance for helping, much appreciated

Comment: Your solution looks correct, what is wrong with it?

Comment: it's inserting "source1" in a unnamed column not column TE

Comment: I don't understand, can you provide create table statements and insert statement for some sample data that illustrates the problem?

Comment: db is sql server 2008. and sure i'll create now

Comment: my apologies lennart, you were correct it did work. not sure why it appeared not to the first go

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to do an update?

```
update target t
    set te = 'source1'
    where exists (select 1 from source s where s.po = t.po and s.ve = t.ve);
```